# use resultset in a for loop

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

```
int i = 0;
while (i < size) {
    String s = username[i];

    String sql4 = "select books1,books2 from " + uname + "a," + s + "b where " + uname + "a.books1=" + s + "b.books2";
    ResultSet rs3 = con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql4);

    System.out.println(sql4);
    while (rs3.next()) {

        count = rs3.getRow();
    }
    i++;
    System.out.println(count);
```

After running this code the output should be `2,1,0,0`
  but instead output is `2,2,2,2`.that is sql query for `i=0`

Comment: why not use select count if you want to know the count?

Comment: You shouldn't concatenate values into queries. Use a prepared statement with parameters instead!

Answer (score 1):

Use `ResultSet.last()` instead of while loop. See following example.

```
count = rs3.last() ? rs3.getRow() : 0;
```

**BAD PRACTICES OF CODE**

Additionally it seems bad statements of your code. You are executing a query, inside a loop which make worse your program in performance. You can use SQL queries using `COUNT`, `JOIN` and another techniques to get your output easily and efficiently with less code.

Comment: Using `rs3.last()` will throw an exception with the default result set type (`TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `count` inside the loop

```
while (i < size) {

count=0;
//execute query
}
```

with your code its printing the previous value of count if no row found.

And instead of using `while(rs3.next())` you can use `select count(*) as cnt...` and use

```
if(rs3.next()){
count = rs3.getInt("cnt");
}
```